# Update and Insert Issue with PHP / MySQL: Some data doesn't get stored

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm having an issue with PHP code where a user submits votes to a MySQL database via AJAX web page into two separate tables at the same time.

Table: vote

Field: Votes

Table: poll

Fields: Multiple

Votes are being inserted properly / fully to the poll table fileds but only partial data or some of the votes are being updated to the vote table >>> votes field.

When I run a test of 100 votes they get stored in the poll table but approx. 70% get stored in the vote table?

It seems like there is something wrong with the insert and update in that when a high volume of votes are coming in they are not stored properly in the vote table.

I have tried increasing the resources for MySQl but it doesn't fix it. I believe that its an issue with the update increment part of this code?

(A) What is the volume of data as a rate at its worst? (B) The moment php gets the post are you logging if so show it. (C) can php merely collect it for now without processig it immediately or must it be user interactive showing results. (D) Are u using mysql_*? (E) can u show actual mysql execute code cuz all i see is array and string prep at a high level –  AsConfused Jun 16 at 5:00

A) Tested 100, 250 & 1000 votes in a minute. Higher volumes give bigger errors, but generally lower tests fail too B) Dont know C) Must be collected immediately and ready for results view for user D) Yes - using MySQL 5.6.22 E) Yes added above –  electrolinks Jun 16 at 8:58

```
/**
 * Vote
 * @since 1.1
 **/
protected function vote(){
    //Kill the Bots and validate request
    if(Main::bot()) die("Access Denied: We do not support bots, unfortunately.");
    if(!isset($_POST["poll_id"]) || !isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]) || $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"]!=="XMLHttpRequest") die("Access Denied: Invalid request.");
    if(!isset($_POST["token"])) die("Access Denied: Token mismatch.");

$this->db->object=TRUE;
    $poll=$this->db->get("poll","BINARY `uniqueid`=?",array("limit"=>1),array($_POST["poll_id"]));
    $options=json_decode($poll->options,TRUE);
    $max=count($options);
    if(is_array($_POST["answer"])){
        $vote=implode(",",Main::clean($_POST["answer"]));
        foreach ($_POST["answer"] as $key => $value) {
            $options[$key]["count"]=$options[$key]["count"]+1;
        }
    }else{
        if(!is_numeric($_POST["answer"]) || $_POST["answer"]>$max) return FALSE;
        $options[$_POST["answer"]]["count"]=$options[$_POST["answer"]]["count"]+1;
        $vote=$_POST["answer"];
    }
    $options=json_encode($options);
    $update=array(
            ":votes"=>($poll->votes + 1),
            ":options"=>$options
        );
    if(isset($_POST["referrer"]) && !empty($_POST["referrer"])){
        $source=Main::clean($_POST["referrer"],3,TRUE);
    }else{
        $source="";
    }
    $insert=array(
            ":pollid" => $poll->id,
            ":polluserid" => $poll->userid,
            ":vote" => $vote,
            /*":ip" => Main::ip(),*/
            ":country" => $this->country(),
            ":source" => $source
        );
        if($this->db->insert("vote",$insert) && $this->db->update("poll","",array("id"=>$poll->id),$update)){
            if($poll->count=="month"){
                Main::cookie($poll->uniqueid,time(),60*60*24*30);
            }elseif ($poll->count=="day") {
                Main::cookie($poll->uniqueid,time(),60*60*24);
            }else{
                Main::cookie($poll->uniqueid,time(),60*60*24*365);
            }
            if(isset($_POST["embed"])){
                $this->results($poll->id,"",TRUE);
            }else{
                $this->results($poll->id);
            }
            return;
        }
    return;
}
```

---

```
/**
* Update Query
* @since 1.0
**/
public function update($table,$field,$where,$param=array()){
    if(empty($field)){
        $field=$this->ph($param);
    }
    //Build Query
    $query="UPDATE {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table SET ";
    if(is_array($field)){
        $count=count($field);
        $i=0;           
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            if($value=="NOW()"){
                $query.="`$key`=$value";
            }else{
                $query.="`$key`=".$this->quote($value,$param);
            }                   
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $query.=",";
            }               
        }
    }else{
        $query.=$field;
    }
    if(is_array($where)){
        $count=count($where);
        $i=0;       
        $query.=" WHERE ";
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $query.="`$key`=".$this->quote($value,$param);
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $query.=" AND ";
            }               
        }
    }else{
        $query.=" WHERE $where";
    }       

    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($param);
    if($this->error_message($result->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$param);
        $this->db_error=$this->error_message($result->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
return TRUE;    
}
```

---

And the schema is:

```
TABLE `vote` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pollid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
`polluserid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`vote` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`country` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`source` text NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

TABLE `poll` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`userid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`open` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`question` text NOT NULL,
`options` text NOT NULL,
`results` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`choice` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`share` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
`pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`theme` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`custom` text NOT NULL,
`count` enum('day','month','off') DEFAULT 'off',
`created` datetime NOT NULL,
`expires` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`uniqueid` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
`votes` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

---

```
 /** 
 * Insert to database
 * @since v1.0
 */
public function insert($table,$parameters=array()){
    $param="";
    $val="";
    $insert= $this->ph($parameters);
    //Build Query
    $query="INSERT INTO {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table";                       
    if(is_array($insert)){
        $count=count($insert);
        $i=0;           
        foreach ($insert as $key => $value) {
            if($parameters[$value]=="NOW()"){
                $val.= "NOW()";
                unset($parameters[$value]);
            }else{
                $val.=$this->quote($value,$parameters);
            }                   
            $param.="`$key`";
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $param.=",";
                $val.=",";
            }               
        }
        $query.=" ($param) VALUES ($val)";
    }       
    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($parameters);
    if($this->error_message($result->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$parameters);
        $this->db_error=$this->error_message($result->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
return TRUE;        
}
/**
 * Update Query
 * @since 1.0
 **/
public function update($table,$field,$where,$param=array()){
    if(empty($field)){
        $field=$this->ph($param);
    }
    //Build Query
    $query="UPDATE {$this->dbinfo["prefix"]}$table SET ";
    if(is_array($field)){
        $count=count($field);
        $i=0;           
        foreach ($field as $key => $value) {
            if($value=="NOW()"){
                $query.="`$key`=$value";
            }else{
                $query.="`$key`=".$this->quote($value,$param);
            }                   
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $query.=",";
            }               
        }
    }else{
        $query.=$field;
    }
    if(is_array($where)){
        $count=count($where);
        $i=0;       
        $query.=" WHERE ";
        foreach ($where as $key => $value) {
            $query.="`$key`=".$this->quote($value,$param);
            if(++$i != $count) {
                $query.=" AND ";
            }               
        }
    }else{
        $query.=" WHERE $where";
    }       

    $result = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute($param);
    if($this->error_message($result->errorInfo())) {
        $this->query=strtr($query,$param);
        $this->db_error=$this->error_message($result->errorInfo());
        exit;
    }
    ++$this->num_queries;
return TRUE;    
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, what does the `$this->db->update()` method look like?

Comment: you have no error handling in your code, after each query you *must* check for success, and if it's not successful then you should immediately handle the error.

Comment: I don't see any errors... But I cant be 100% sure Im logging them properly.

Edit: I think this is the $this->db->update() method now added above?

Comment: Ok however I don't know how to add error handling to the code

Comment: (A) What is the volume of data as a rate at its worst? (B) The moment php gets the post are you logging if so show it. (C) can php merely collect it for now without processig it immediately or `must` it be user interactive showing results. (D) Are u using mysql_*? (E) can u show actual mysql execute code cuz all i see is array and string prep at a high level

Comment: A) Tested 100, 250 & 1000 votes in a minute. Higher volumes give bigger errors, but generally lower tests fail too

B) Dont know

C) Must be collected immediately and ready for results view for user

D) Yes - using MySQL 5.6.22 

E) Yes added above